# Grails Restful file upload with progress bar

Tags: rest, grails

I am creating an application where I want to upload a file to a Restful service with Progress bar. I completed uploading a file using REST but I don't know how to show the progress bar/or percentage of how much of data is uploaded.

Here is the controller's code:

```
def uploadDocument() {

    if(!params?.documentFile){
        render '{"success":false , "message":"Cannot upload an empty file !!!"}'
    }
    def status = ['success':true,"message":"file_uploaded"]
    try{
        CommonsMultipartFile file = params.documentFile
        def fileLocation ="C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\temp_file_upload\\${file.originalFilename}"
        file.transferTo(new File( fileLocation))

    }catch(Exception e){
        status.put("success", false)
        status.put("message", "Error_uplodaing the file")
        e.printStackTrace(System.out)
    }
    render status as JSON
}
```

GSP CODE :

```
 <g:uploadForm controller="FileUpload" action="uploadDocument"  style="height: 500px;">
<fieldset class="buttons">
            <g:submitButton name="upload" class="save" value="Upload" />
        </fieldset>
    </g:uploadForm>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I think for progress bar on file upload you need to user ajax file upload check this link http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/